# Menu bar Separator in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

In my Flex Application define the menu bar in Grid.

How to do Separator for each item?

How to Expand(Specific size) Menu bar for entire window(ie or chrome)?

Actually this is my Sample code.

```
<Canvas id="canvas_afterLogin" width="100%" visible="false">
        <Grid width="100%">
           <GridRow id="header1" width="100%" horizontalAlign="center">

               <GridItem horizontalAlign="left" width="100%">
                 <Image source="assets/sitsLogo.png" width="60" height="60"/>
             </GridItem>

               <GridItem width="100%">
                     <MenuBar id="myMenuBar0" width="100%"
                             borderColor="#C8DCF5" color="#000000"
                             cornerRadius="0" dataProvider="{xml}"
                             fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14" fontStyle="normal"
                             fontWeight="normal" itemClick="myMenuBar_itemClickHandler(event)"
                             labelField="@label" themeColor="#06FC8B"/>
                </GridItem>
                <GridItem width="100%" horizontalAlign="right">
                    <Button height="22" label="Logout" click="logoutUser(event)"
                            color="#000000" fontSize="12" themeColor="#B0D2D4"/>
                </GridItem>
           </GridRow>
      </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

and dataProvider `xml` is

```
<XMLList id="xml">
    <menuitem label="Home"/>        
    <menuitem label="Contacts">         
        <menuitem label="Find"/>
    </menuitem>
                   <menuitem label="Profile">
    </menuitem>         
    <menuitem label="Messages">
        <menuitem label="DetailsSearch"/>   
    </menuitem>         
    <menuitem label="Classes">
        <menuitem label="LiveView"/>
    </menuitem>         
    <menuitem label="Reports">
        <menuitem label="Money_Form"/>
    </menuitem>     
    <menuitem label="Money" color="#112233">
        <menuitem label="Receive_Founds"/>
    </menuitem>     
    <menuitem label="Confilcts">
        <menuitem label="Myconflicts"/>         
    </menuitem>         
    <menuitem label="Courses">
        <menuitem label=""/>
    </menuitem> 
    <menuitem label="eC9 Deck">
        <menuitem label="Contact_Us"/>
    </menuitem>
</XMLList>
```

Please Help me ... How to give separator for each Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<menuitem type="separator"/>
```

For more details, see [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b1e.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b23).